# How to use Update-Database command

Tags: entity-framework-core

- I'm learning Entity Framework Core(everything is last version), at first lesson when i'm creating a db from a class.
- after "Add-Migration v1" is **"Build succeeded."** - everything is working, i am adding data and fetching it.
- From the lesson i should "Update-Database v1" and here is the problem- error.

  Failed executing DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  CREATE TABLE [Users] (
  [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  [Name] nvarchar(max) NULL,
  [Age] int NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
  );

"here is already an object named 'Users' in the database. "

- This error didn't bother me till everything is working, but at lesson nr 2 when we should change variable types, add columns ... only **Add-Migration Vx** is not working without **Update-Database Vx**, so to solve, for every update, i delete db and Migrations folder and going along with lessons only with **Add-Migration Vx** - also working.
- It is a way to update the changes without *Update-Database Vx** ? if someone know how i could solve the error of  "here is already an object named ... in the database. "  thanks

Comment: Actually, if you only run "Add-Migration vx" commands you should not be able to add or fetch data, add-migration does not apply changes to your database. add-migration just generates code that is going to be applied when you run Update-Database, also I think it's better to just execute "Update-Database" without specifying any migration, that way it will execute all the migrations that are not currently applied to your database

Comment: @sebrojas - looking to logs, doesn't matter if i write version or not version to Update-Database because it will apply the last Migration                                     
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Applying migration '20200728144708_v1'.

Comment: Imagine you run the following commands Add-Migration v1 Add-Migration v2 Add-Migration v3. if you run "Update-Database v1" it will only execute v1 migration therefore if you run "Update-Database v2" v1 and v2 will be executed, but if you only run "Update-Database" v1, v2 and v3 will be applied if they haven't been applied yet